# Save fragment state when change of fragment A to fragment B

Tags: android, view, android-fragments, savestate

I have a fragment A and a fragment B.

In fragment A  i do a inflation of a some views to inside a container. Then i change to a fragment B, and when i turn to fragment A, the views that inflate are gone and i lost the data inside this views.

Anyone know what is the problem?
Thanks by your time and help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the life cycle of a Fragment: `http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle`

you can use the methods `onSaveInstanceState()` to save data and `onCreateView()` to reload important data.

you should create all your UI data inside the `onCreateView()` instead of the Fragment constructor and then it will be called each time you re-create the View.